# What are the advantages of useRef() instead of just declaring a variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Looking at the hooks docs and some blogs we understand that when using useRef() we have a mutable value stored.

[Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

> You might be familiar with refs primarily as a way to access the DOM. If you pass a ref object to React with , React will set its .current property to the corresponding DOM node whenever that node changes.
>
> However, useRef() is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around similar to how you’d use instance fields in classes.
>
> This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object yourself is that useRef will give you the same ref object on every render.

What advantages does this give us over just declaring and using a variable with `let`?

Code ex:

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
const MyFunctionalComponent = (props) => {
    const refVariable = useRef('value');
    //versus
    let letVariable = 'value';
}
```

Follow up:
The answers given were helpful, and combined with some testing gave me the understanding I needed. If anyone comes across this having trouble with the concept, the way I understand it now is:

- You can have instance variables, but they are really instant, and every re-render re-initializes them.
- useRef() gives you something more permanent, like useState() but updating doesn't trigger re-render, very useful if you are doing a lot of manipulation in a chaining fashion, but wouldn't want to trigger a re-render until the end
- useState() should only be tied to variables used by a UI element, as any change to state will trigger re-render of the whole component. Do not have a chain of actions that manipulate state along the way, use refs until the end of the chain.

Comment: Do you mean using a variable with `let` outside of the component? If necessary, please give an example.

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie: I added a minimal example of what I'm asking, but I think Jayce444 has the answer as I need it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm changing my answer and referring people to Arman's below, since it's the more apt one. In essence, for functional components the **entire** function gets run every time it re-renders. Which means variables that are initialized with a simple `let x = 5;` in the body of the function will get re-initialized every render, resetting them. That's the reason we need hooks like `useRef`, it gives a *reference* to a value that persists between renders

Comment: Can you add any information or links explaining why you can't? I'm totally new with these hooks, and not all that adept yet with React in general so I want to understand as much as possible about this.

Comment: Functional components is just an equivalent of a render function of a React.Component class. So with all the class instance variables capability excluded out, it's not possible to define instance variables. Hooks offers useRef for the equivalent use case.

Comment: Poor explanation. To put it simple: variables forget their value between renders. `useRef()` allows you to remember the value, just like class property would be stored in a class.

Comment: A question which popped into my mind directly was, what if I define the variable **outside** of the function instead. This however, doesn't work if you create multiple components in the same file because the variable is not bound to the component (as opposed to a `useRef` ref). Here's some nice example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-57444154-react-refs-closures-forked-also-q-60554573-xcx0x

Comment: to those saying you cant have an instance variable, what if I just did a normal variable declaration like so "var someValue". That seems to be doable in react function components no problem

Answer (score 17):

The last sentence describes it clearly:

> useRef will give you the same ref object on every render.

If you declare a simple javascript variable yourself, it will be updated on each render. Refs are used when you need to persist some value during re-renders (Besides using the ref attribute for DOM node reference)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that. The variable would belong to the component, not the render function, so why would it get updated on each render?

Comment: useRef is a hook which is supposed to be used in Function Components, you are talking about Class Components. FCs will be called on each re-render.