# What are the advantages of useRef() instead of just declaring a variable in the module scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Similar to [What are the advantages of useRef() instead of just declaring a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60554573/what-are-the-advantages-of-useref-instead-of-just-declaring-a-variable) but I am asking specifically in the module scope rather than the function scope.

e.g.

```
const webClient = axios.create();

export const FunctionalComponent = ({children}) => {
   ...
   webClient.get(...)
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
export const FunctionalComponent = ({children}) => {

   const webClientRef = useRef(axios.create());
   ...
   webClientRef.current.get(...)
   ...
}
```

I can't really see any difference aside from being able to refer to something that is only available in the react component.  Or just limitting the scope to just the component.

Comment: A module-scoped variable is static and shared between all instances of the component.

Comment: useRef is usually used when you need access to the rendered DOM node - Not the React component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a single webClient, no matter how many of the component you render:

```
const webClient = axios.create();

export const FunctionalComponent = ({children}) => {
   ...
   webClient.get(...)
   ...
}
```

This gives you one for each instance of the component:

```
export const FunctionalComponent = ({children}) => {

   const webClientRef = useRef(axios.create());
   ...
   webClientRef.current.get(...)
   ...
}
```

So both have their uses. It's just a matter of whether you need one or multiple.